# Meld: can I clear the read-only flag on file?

Tags: meld

The version control system that I have to use (Perforce) by default gives me read-only files. I want to move some changes from one directory to another, and the target files are read-only. I want to clear the read-only flag from the Meld UI. (Otherwise I will have to manually locate changed files in the directory tree, which is just stupid.)

**How do I clear the read-only flag on file from the meld UI?**

(Something ready-to-use? Or maybe it is easy to write some small extension?)

Answer (score 0):

*C:\Windows\clearro.cmd:*

```
attrib -r %1
```

(Menu)--Meld-Preferences--the [Editor] tab

Uncheck "Use default system editor"

specify `clearro.cmd` as *Editor command*.

Now, to clear the read-only attribute, you right-click the mouse on the file and choose "Open Externally" from the menu. Instead of opening the external editor, it will invoke `clearro.cmd` on the file. If you need to open the file, you can go to preferences and check the checkbox.

Yes, it should be an external tool invocation rather than an editor hack, but this at least works.

(Did not try this on Linux, but it should be something like `chmod a+w $1` in the file `clearro.sh`, don't forget to `chmod a+x clearro.sh` to make it executable.)